# How to solve ${\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} x\cos x\,dx}$ using integration by parts?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

$${\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} x\cos x\,dx}$$

Would the method to solve this be integration by parts?

Comment: Yes, the integration by parts would work nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, integration by parts is a good idea. Indeed, we get
$$\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}x\cos x\;dx=\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}x\;d(\sin x)=x\sin x\bigg|_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}-\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\sin x\;dx,$$
and you can easily compute the rest.

Comment: This is too much. Since the question is "Would the method to solve this be integration by parts?", the proper answer should be "Yes, it would".

Comment: @Venus: Strictness is the highly quality for mathematicians?

Answer (score 2):

Integration by parts will work fine.  But here's another fun way of doing it:

$\int x\cos(\beta x)dx = \int \frac {d}{d\beta}\sin(\beta x)dx = \frac{d}{d\beta}\int \sin(\beta x)dx = \frac {d}{d\beta}\frac {-\cos(\beta x)}{\beta} = \frac{\sin(\beta x)x\beta + \cos(\beta x)}{\beta^2}$

Now set $\beta = 1$.$\ \ $ :)